# How to properly escape parameters for JSONB deep query in node-postgres

Tags: jsonb, node-postgres

When bypassing an ORM and doing direct queries to `node-postgres`, there are a nice pile of weird edge issues to keep in mind. For example, you have probably already encountered the fact that camelCaseColumns have to be in double-quotes, and also parameterized type casting…

```
client.query(`SELECT id, "authorFirstName", "authorLastName" FROM books WHERE isbn = $1::int`, [1444723448]`)
client.query(`SELECT id FROM books WHERE "authorLastName" = $1::string`, ['King']`)
```

JSON and JSONB types add another aspect of weirdness. The important thing to keep in mind is, "$1" is not merely a variable placeholder; it is an indicator of a discrete unit of information.

Given a table where `characters` is a column of type JSONB, this will not work…

```
client.query(
  `SELECT id FROM books WHERE characters @> ([ {'name': $1::string} ])`,
  ['Roland Deschain']
)
```

This fails because the unit of information is the JSON object, not a string you're inserting into a blob of text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more clear when one looks at a simpler SELECT and an UPDATE…

```
const userData = await client.query(
  `SELECT characters FROM books WHERE id = $1::uuid`,
  [ some_book_id ]
)
const newCharacters = JSON.stringify([
  ...userData[0].characters, 
  { name: 'Jake' }, 
  { name: 'Eddie' }, 
  { name: 'Odetta' }
])
await this.databaseService.executeQuery(
  `UPDATE books SET characters = $1::jsonb WHERE id = $2::uuid`,
  [ newCharacters, some_book_id ]
)
```

The deep search query should be formed thusly:

```
const searchBundle = JSON.stringify([
  {'name': 'Roland Deschain'}
])
client.query(
  `SELECT id FROM books WHERE characters @> ($1::jsonb)`,
  [searchBundle]
)
```